# Match but not return regular expression between two matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to retrieve two distinct items without matching the term in between using regular expressions:

`[[A]] son of [[B]]`

I thought this would work:

`\[\[[A-Za-z\s]+\]\](?:(.*son of.*))\[\[[\|,A-Za-z\s]+\]\]`

but it's not quite working. How can I match A and B without returning "son of"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have a string like `[[Worf]] son of [[Mogh]]`, from which you want to "return" (i.e. match) `[[Worf]]` and `[[Mogh]]`. To do so, you'll need capturing groups (parentheses) around the portions of the regular expression you want to capture (aka "return"). In order to not return `son of`, you'll also need to remove the capturing group you have in there (nested within the `(?:...)`).

In code:

```
>>> s = '[[Worf]] son of [[Mogh]]'
>>> p = re.compile('(\[\[[A-Za-z\s]+\]\])(?:.*son of.*)(\[\[[\|,A-Za-z\s]+\]\])')
>>> print p.match(s).groups()
('[[Worf]]', '[[Mogh]]')
```

If you're using the `.groups()` method to get the matched sections, you can also drop the non-capturing group around `.*son of.*`, which may make the RE more readable (I happen to think it makes the intention -- not to capture that -- more clear).

Answer (score 1):

I would echo dcrosta's answer, although personally I prefer using named captures. While using named captures makes the regex itself a little harder to read, it gives you dictionary-like access to the capture:

```
>>> mw_string = "[[Duras]] son of [[Ja'rod]]"
>>> son_re = re.compile('\[\[(?P<son>[^\]]+)\]\](?:.*son of.*)\[\[(?P<parent>[^\]]+)\]\]')
>>> print son_re.match(mw_string).group("son")
Duras
>>> print son_re.match(mw_string).group("parent")
Ja'rod
```

The advantage of using name captures is that you might be creating an entire set of various regexen, each with a defined set of arguments you want to pull out of the match in a particular meaningful order (for example, "[[Ja'rod]]'s son [[Duras]]").

Since it looks like you're parsing MediaWiki, it may be useful for you to use [mwlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mwlib/) to iterate over the links and then find those that have "son of" in their surrounding context. This would definitely help for the various special forms of links not matched by this set of regexen.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: `(\[\[[A-Za-z\s]+\]\])(?:.*son of.*)(\[\[[\|,A-Za-z\s]+\]\])`

```
p = re.compile(r"(\[\[[A-Za-z\s]+\]\])(?:.*son of.*)(\[\[[\|,A-Za-z\s]+\]\])")
m = p.match("[[A]] son of [[B]]")
print m.groups()
# ('[[A]]', '[[B]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> a = "\[\[([A-Za-z]+)\]\] son of \[\[([A-Za-z]+)\]\]"
>> p = re.compile(a)
>> m = p.match("[[A]] son of [[B]]")
>> m.groups()
('A', 'B')
```